# Hightlight the multiple line text of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to highlight the text of div tag.

It works when There is a single line but does not work for multiple:

```
function SelectChar(el, iStart, iLength) {
    var div = el
    if (document.createRange) {
        var textNode = div.firstChild;
        if (textNode.data.length > 1) {
            var rangeObj = document.createRange();
            rangeObj.setStart(textNode, iStart);
            rangeObj.setEnd(textNode, iLength);
            selection = window.getSelection();
            selection.removeAllRanges();
            selection.addRange(rangeObj);
        }
    }
}
```

where `textbox` is content editable div tag.

**UPDATE**

```
<div contenteditable="true" id="textbox">The
text
is given
and</div>
```

Any suggestion please?
This is the plugin `auto.js` that is used to suggest the word..in that I want to do selection portion for multiple line text in div tag

```
   AutoSuggestControl.prototype.typeAhead = function (sSuggestion /*:String*/) {
        //    debugger
        //check for support of typeahead functionality
        var range = document.createRange();
        var selection = window.getSelection();
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range);
        if (selection) {
            var lastSpace = this.textbox.innerText.lastIndexOf(" ");
            var lastQuote = this.textbox.innerText.lastIndexOf("'");
            var lastHypen = this.textbox.innerText.lastIndexOf("-");
            var lastDoubleQuote = this.textbox.innerText.lastIndexOf('"');
            var lastEnter = this.textbox.innerText.lastIndexOf("\n");
            var lastIndex = Math.max(lastSpace, lastEnter, lastQuote, lastHypen, lastDoubleQuote) + 1;
            var contentStripped = this.textbox.innerText.substring(0, lastIndex);
            var lastWord = this.textbox.innerText.substring(lastIndex, this.textbox.innerText.length);
            this.textbox.innerText = contentStripped + sSuggestion; //.replace(lastWord,"");
            var start = this.textbox.innerText.length - sSuggestion.replace(lastWord, "").length;
            var end = this.textbox.innerText.length;
            SelectChar(document.getElementById("textbox"), start, end);
        }
    };
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yypgs1bp/)

Comment: Can you show us the div with inside text? Also the code you use to call the `SelectChar` method?

Comment: Please create a running and working code snippet in the internal StackOverflow fiddler

Comment: @Mivaweb please check udpated question

Comment: Please include your HTML portions too.

Comment: yah added @LibinCJacob

Comment: @AndreaLigios added jsfiddle please check it out

Comment: Can you explain how it should work ? It is not clear to me

Comment: http://atmb4u.github.io/AutoJS/ this is the plugin..I converted textarea to div tag which set `editable=true`..in single line it shows suggestion like in plugin's example but in multiple line it doesnot show..because of `div.firstChild`..I want to do it work on multipleline @AndreaLigios

Comment: Ah ok. But then 1) your fiddle is not working even with a single line, 2) this is probably not a 5 mins thing to do and 3) why are you using a div instead of a textarea ? Not for esthetic purposes, since a textarea can be styled exacly as a div, so what ? BTW cool plugin

Comment: thnx :P ...I have to use div tag only..U can give me any suggestion regarding that..and it is working for single line`<div contenteditable="true" id="textbox">The and</div>` try above one@AndreaLigios

Comment: It doesn't work on FF. But I've tried now and it does in Chrome

Comment: ahun..any suggestion plz @AndreaLigios

Comment: You need to modify the `AutoSuggestControl.prototype.typeAhead = function (sSuggestion /*:String*/) {` function, by recalculating ALL the variables in there with a position relative to the current line, not to the whole content. So "lastDoubleQuote" for example must be last double quote in the line, not in the div, and so all the others. Try checking for <br> before and after your current line, then extract the current line and use it as a value to be used by the function instead of the whole content. Start with that, good luck

Comment: actually I am thinking same thing but the problem is in `setStart` it will accept node only in first parameter..I pass div id in that but throws error of `not is a node in first parameter` @AndreaLigios